# Why is only the last message entered being displayed

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone help me out I have a user messaging in my profile and it only displays the last message how would i display all the messages for that user.

Below is the code i have already:

```
<?php 
    $message_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
    while($get_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_list)) {
        $message_subject = $get_message['subject'];
        $message_body    = $get_message['body'];
        $message_from    = $get_message['from_user'];
        $message_date    = $get_message['date'];
        $message_to      = $get_message['to_user'];
        }
        if($message_to === $user_data['username']) {


                echo 
                '
                <center>
                <table border="2" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%"><center>From</center></td>
                            <td width="20%"><center>Date / Time</center></td>
                            <td><center>Message</center></td>
                            <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                            <td width="7%"><center>Delete</center></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </center>';
                echo 
                '
                <center>
                <table border="1" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" height="35px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%"><center>'. $message_from .'</center></td>
                            <td width="20%"><center>'. $message_date .'</center></td>
                            <td><center><br>'. $message_body .'<br></center><br></td>
                            <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                            <td width="7%"><center><form><input type="checkbox" name="delete"></form></center></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </center>';
        } else {
            echo '<center>you have no messages</center>';
        }
    ?>
```

All its displaying is the last message entered not all.

Comment: You need to put your html inside the loop in your code its outside the loop so last result will be displayed

Comment: Thanks you @MKhalidJunaid what a numpty i am i missed out the } at end

Answer (score 1):

Problem was while loop you were ended early, try this one code instead of yours

```
    <?php 
        $message_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
        while($get_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_list)) {
            $message_subject = $get_message['subject'];
            $message_body    = $get_message['body'];
            $message_from    = $get_message['from_user'];
            $message_date    = $get_message['date'];
            $message_to      = $get_message['to_user'];

            if($message_to === $user_data['username']) {


                    echo 
                    '
                    <center>
                    <table border="2" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15%"><center>From</center></td>
                                <td width="20%"><center>Date / Time</center></td>
                                <td><center>Message</center></td>
                                <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                                <td width="7%"><center>Delete</center></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    </center>';
                    echo 
                    '
                    <center>
                    <table border="1" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" height="35px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15%"><center>'. $message_from .'</center></td>
                                <td width="20%"><center>'. $message_date .'</center></td>
                                <td><center><br>'. $message_body .'<br></center><br></td>
                                <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                                <td width="7%"><center><form><input type="checkbox" name="delete"></form></center></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    </center>';
            } else {
                echo '<center>you have no messages</center>';
            }
}
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks you @SagarPanchal what a numpty i am i missed out the } at end

Answer (score 1):

Just need to move one bracket and it should work!

```
<?php 
$message_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
while($get_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_list)) {
    $message_subject = $get_message['subject'];
    $message_body    = $get_message['body'];
    $message_from    = $get_message['from_user'];
    $message_date    = $get_message['date'];
    $message_to      = $get_message['to_user'];
    //DELETED BRACKET HERE
    if($message_to === $user_data['username']) {


            echo 
            '
            <center>
            <table border="2" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%"><center>From</center></td>
                        <td width="20%"><center>Date / Time</center></td>
                        <td><center>Message</center></td>
                        <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                        <td width="7%"><center>Delete</center></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </center>';
            echo 
            '
            <center>
            <table border="1" bordercolor="" style="background-color:" width="85%" height="35px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%"><center>'. $message_from .'</center></td>
                        <td width="20%"><center>'. $message_date .'</center></td>
                        <td><center><br>'. $message_body .'<br></center><br></td>
                        <td width="15%"><center>Reply</center></td>
                        <td width="7%"><center><form><input type="checkbox" name="delete"></form></center></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </center>';
    } else {
        echo '<center>you have no messages</center>';
    }

 } //PUT IT HERE
?>
```

But just as a warning this will output "you have no messages" every time there is a message in the system even if it isn't to the user! I would just change your query to include a `WHERE` clause based on the user data

```
    $username = $user_data['username'];
    $message_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to_user` = '$username'");
```

Comment: Thank you @Chitowns24 I will add that in :)